# How to distinguish between "less" and "more" in a terms of text mining

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, word2vec

I'm trying to extract "more" or "less" information from the text. But the word similarity using W2V between words like "more"("huge", "increase", "improve") has almost equal similarities with words like "less"("lower", "little", "reduce").

How to get a distinguishable similarities?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common challenge with word-vectors, as even words that we consider to be 'antonyms', like say `'hot'` and `'cold'`, are usually very-similar in standard word-vector spaces.

Typically, in many aspects *except* one-of-contrast, such words are otherwise very-alike (compared to all other words): they're the same part-of-speech,  refer to similar qualities, & often appear in exact same contexts as drop-in replacements for each other – when you want to flip one-of-many ways something could be described.

Comparative-modifiers like 'more' or 'less' present a special challenge as their meaning easily flips based on surrounding context. Water that is 'more' pure is 'less' contaminated. Furniture that is 'more' heavy is 'less' easy-to-move. A 'huge' problem has a 'tiny' chance of having quick solution. An 'increase' in chances-of-success means a 'decrease' in chances-of-failure.

Can you give more concrete examples of the task you're attempting – for example input texts/words, and desired results, and the unsatisfactory results you've received with your initial tries?

Using off-the-shelf individual word-vectors (or an off-the-shelf standard training method) may not be enough - but perhaps some refinements can get you further.

For example, you've already listed 4 examples of your `'more'`-like words, and 4 examples of your `'less'`-like words. What if you compile longer representative lists, and judge some new unknown token based on its *one closest* similarity to any in either set? Or, some tally of the number of times the candidate comes closer to the `'more'` examples than the paired `'less'` examples?

It's hard to make further suggestions without a better picture of the true underlying task/goal. And, if it's understanding hgihly-contextual texts, where such comparators' absolute meanings depend on a lot on surrounding words, simple word-vectors may not be up to the task.